# Split 2 csv files into smaller sets of files based on unique values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, split

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I just couldn't find a simple example.

I have 2 large CSV files that I would like to split based on the unique values in the `Location` & `LocationType` Column. I would like to store the split csv files into sub-directories for each value in a folder named  `item/{item_name}` where `item_name` is the unique value in Location & Location_type.

- Location.csv

[image: CSV-1]

- Location-type.csv

[image: CSV-2]

- Each split csv file should have the same header line as the parent file
- If the sub-directory already exists, delete those files before writing the new files.

End result would be a directory called `item` with two sub-directories called `fm5` & `fm15` with our split CSV files stored. location.csv & location_type.csv

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> would like to know the workflow for this type of project

- open the file
- sort the contents on the desired column
- group by the desired column
- write each group to a new file